# c# Substring Equivalent of array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, substring, equivalent

Is there a substring equivalent for an array?

Input `new char[] foo = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}`

If this was a String `abcdef` I would use `.Substring(0, 2)` and get `ab`

Is there a built in method that would give me `char[] {'a', 'b'}` if the input indexes were `0, 2`?

Code Example

```
char[] foo = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
char[] bar = foo.**Method**(0, 2); //what can I do here?

Console.WriteLine(bar);
//Output would be` **ab**
```

I know I could just convert the Char array back to a String, use Substring and back to a Char Array. But that would take some extra lines of Code and I want to know, if it is possible with only 1 built-in Method.

Comment: There is an `ArraySegment` class you can use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a single method for this but you can use Linq to get the same affect like

```
var newArr = set.Skip(n).Take(k).ToArray();
```

Further step could be writing an extension method

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static T[] Subsequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> arr,int startIndex, int length)
    {
        return arr.Skip(startIndex).Take(length).ToArray();
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
var newset = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.Subsequence(1, 2);
```

Comment: Also look at `ArraySegment<T>`.

Comment: How could you end the segment on a specific index? This looks like you can get the array from a specified index to the end of the array only